# What do you do when a spell or something says that the target needs to do a saving throw without a number for the throw?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, saving-throw

For command, it states, "The target must succeed on a Wisdom saving throw or follow the command on its next turn" without any context to how high the target needs to roll for it to succeed. What does the target need to roll to succeed that saving throw? Is the number specific for command or is it the same for all spells like this? I'd like to get all the info I can for this.

Comment: I have closed your question as I feel it has effectively been asked before. Know that this isn't a bad thing and it actually helps people find the linked question more easily; that said, if you feel your question is *not* answered in there, feel free to [edit] your question or leave a comment explaining why. But also hello and welcome to RPG.SE! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already done so and if you need further guidance you can visit the [help] or drop a comment here. Best of luck and happy gaming!

Answer (score 4):

#### Use your spell save DC.

From the rules for spell casting:

> Many spells specify that a target can make a saving throw to avoid some or all of a spell's effects. The spell specifies the ability that the target uses for the save and what happens on a success or failure.
>
> The DC to resist one of your spells equals 8 + your spellcasting ability modifier + your proficiency bonus + any special modifiers.